# Need to combine all csv data into single file of nested folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to combine all csv files data into single csv file using batch script

the folder structure is as follows

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLog\Export\20200727\AL-Comp_Outbound\20200726\ (multiple csv's present here)

So under "Export" there are multiple folders like "20200727...20200678" and in those folders the common sub folder name is  AL-Comp_Outbound which further has a sub folder  "20200728...20200728" that contain csv files.

I need to find the folder with name AL-Comp_Outbound navigate to it and then parse through all the sub folders that has csv files and combine it together.

i tried to do but it with below query but it search for all the folders present in the directory, I need only need csv files from all folders having common name as "AL-Comp_Outbound". Also need to remove repetition header

```
@echo off 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD "%~dp0"

SET "SUMMARY_FILE=sumfile.csv"
DEL /F "%SUMMARY_FILE%" 2>nul

SET "LINE_COUNT=1"

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%p IN (`dir c:\ /s /b /ad ^| find "AL-Comp_Outbound"`) DO (

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2^>nul') DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol=ÿ" %%s IN ("%%~f") DO (
        >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%" ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%%s
        SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
    )
)
)

    POPD

    ENDLOCAL
```

Any help is truly appreciated !!!

===============================================================

Below is the code which i tried to get it work but it keeps on going to another folder  "AL-Comp_NetworkShare" to fetch CSV file while i only need csv files from sub directories in "AL-Comp_Outbound"

```
REM @echo off 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD "%~dp0"

SET "SUMMARY_FILE=sumfile.csv"
DEL /F "%SUMMARY_FILE%" 2>nul

SET "LINE_COUNT=1"


For /D %%G In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\*") Do For /D %%H In ("%%G\AL-Comp_Outbound\*")Do (PushD %%H,

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2^>nul') DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol=ÿ" %%s IN ("%%~f") DO (
        >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%" ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%%s
        SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
    )
)
,POPD)

ENDLOCAL
```

==================================output=================

```
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export> .\me.bat

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>REM @echo off

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>PUSHD "C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\"

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>SET "SUMMARY_FILE=sumfile.csv"

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>DEL /F "sumfile.csv"  2>nul

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>SET "LINE_COUNT=1"

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>For / %G In ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\*") Do For / %H In ("%G\AL-Comp_Outbound\*") Do (
PushD %H,
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2>nul') DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s IN ("%~f") DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
 POPD
)

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>For / %H In ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200722\AL-Comp_Outbound\*") Do (
PushD %H,
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2>nul') DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s IN ("%~f") DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
 POPD
)

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>For / %H In ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200723\AL-Comp_Outbound\*") Do (
PushD %H,
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2>nul') DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s IN ("%~f") DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
 POPD
)

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>For / %H In ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200724\AL-Comp_Outbound\*") Do (
PushD %H,
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2>nul') DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s IN ("%~f") DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
 POPD
)

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>For / %H In ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200725\AL-Comp_Outbound\*") Do (
PushD %H,
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2>nul') DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s IN ("%~f") DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
 POPD
)

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>(
PushD C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200725\AL-Comp_Outbound\20200715,
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /S /B *.csv 2>nul') DO (FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s IN ("%~f") DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
 POPD
)
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export>(FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %s **IN ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200722\AL-Comp_NetworkShare\20200702\20200702_Ncomp-fjt03063.csv")** DO (
ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%s 1>>"sumfile.csv"
 SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
) )
```

Comment: I would assume that something like this would work for you, **1.** `For /D %%G In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\DLog\Export\*"`, **2.** `)Do For /D %%H In ("%%G\AL-Comp_Outbound\*")Do (PushD %%H`, **3.** `Rem Do your work here`, and **4.** `PopD)` Obviously you'd insert your specific code to combine your csv files between lines `2.` and `4.`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the approach       

REM @echo off 

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD "%~dp0"

SET "SUMMARY_FILE=sumfile.csv"
DEL /F "%SUMMARY_FILE%" 2>nul

SET "LINE_COUNT=1"


For /D %%G In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\*") Do ( For /D %%H In ("%%G\AL-Comp_Outbound\*")Do (PushD %%H,

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('*.csv 2^>nul') DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* eol=ÿ" %%s IN ("%%~f") DO (
        >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%" ECHO !LINE_COUNT!%%s
        SET /A LINE_COUNT+=1
    )
)
)
POPD
)
)
ENDLOCAL

Comment: Of course it works. What you mean is that you haven't implemented it properly! To begin with you have unbalanced parentheses there!

Comment: The script works but it searches from another folder. I want the script to search only from AL-Comp_Outbound. I have added the output in body section of this page

Answer (score 0):

This simple and straightforward Batch file should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Go to base folder
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLog\Export

rem Process all folders here
for /D %%a in (*) do (

   rem Enter to each folder AND to the desired subfolder
   pushd "%%a\AL-Comp_Outbound"

   rem Parse through all subfolders here
   for /D %%b in (*) do (

      rem Combine all .csv files in each subfolder
      for %%f in ("%%b\*.csv") do (
         if not exist sumfile.tmp (
            copy "%%f" sumfile.tmp
         ) else (
            more +1 "%%f" >> sumfile.tmp
         )
      )

   )

   rem Go back to base folder
   popd

)
```

Comment: The script run but shows warnings like    C:\Users\username\Desktop\DLPLog\Export\20200727\AL-Comp_Outbound>(if not exist sumfile.csv (copy "20200727\20200727_ncomp -n196666.csv" sumfile.csv )  else (more +1 "20200727\20200727_ncomp -n196666.csv"  1>>sumfile.csv ) )
Too many arguments in command line. Also it creates sumfile.csv in every AL-Comp_Outbound and does not create a common one in the base path of export folder. I want all csv data to be copied to base folder in a single csv.